# Extract alphanumeric value from varchar column

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, sql-like, alphanumeric

I have a table which contains a column having **alphanumeric** values which is stored as a string. I have multiple values in that column having values such as `F4737`, `00Y778`, `PP0098`, `XXYYYZ` etc.

I want to **extract values starting with a series of F and must have numeric values in that row.**
Alphanumeric column is the unique column having unique values but the rest of the columns contain duplicate values in my table.

Futhermore, once these values are extracted I would like to pick up the **max value** from the duplicate row,for eg:

*Suppose I have `F4737` and `F4700` as a unique Alphanumeric row, then `F4737` must be extracted from it.*

I have written a query like this but the numeric values are not getting extracted from this query:

```
select max(Alplanumeric) 
from Customers 
where Alplanumeric '%[F0-9]%
```

or

```
select max(Alplanumeric) 
from Customers 
where Alplanumeric like '%[0-9]%' 
and Alplanumeric like 'F%'**
```

I run the above query but I am only getting the F series if I remove the numeric part from the above query. How do I extract both, the F starting series as well as the numeric values included in that row?

Comment: If you want to do operations like this, then you should store the values in a junction table, with one row per customer and one row per code.

Comment: `LIKE` doesn't support regular expressions. You need to use `similar to`, the `~` operator or `regexp_matches()`. See the manual for details: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html

Comment: I dont want to separate the values in a junction table or use regexp matches as it would increase the query execution . I tried this query : select max(CustomerName) from Customers where CustomerName like '%4%' and CustomerName like 'F%' , this one works but only for numeric value 4. I would like to add other numeric values too in this query.

Comment: How do you know it "*would increase the query execution*" if you don't try it? Btw: `like '%[0-9]%' ` will look for values that have a `[` followed by a `-` followed by a `]` anywhere in the column.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please provide an exact table definition, some sample rows and the expected result. Best in the form of valid `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements. Among other things "max value" is ambiguous. Maximum of the numeric part (treated as number) or the text value? And *always* your version of Postgres. By "Alplanumeric" you mean "Alphanumeric" I suppose?

Answer (score 0):

Going out on a limb, you might be looking for a query like this:

```sql
SELECT *, substring(alphanumeric, '^F(\d+)')::int AS nr
FROM   customers 
WHERE  alphanumeric ~ '^F\d+' 
ORDER  BY nr DESC NULLS LAST
        , alphanumeric
LIMIT  1;
```

The `WHERE` conditions is a regular expression match, the expression is anchored to the start, so it can use an index. Ideally:

```
CREATE INDEX customers_alphanumeric_pattern_ops_idx ON customers
(alphanumeric text_pattern_ops);
```

This returns the one row with the highest (extracted) numeric value in `alphanumeric` among rows starting with 'F' followed by one ore more digits.

About the index:

- [PostgreSQL LIKE query performance variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566717/postgresql-like-query-performance-variations/13452528#13452528)

About pattern matching:

- [Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10696/3684)

---

Ideally, you should store the leading text and the following numeric value in ***separate*** columns to make this more efficient. You don't necessarily need more tables like has been suggested.